# Rasa run actions is stuck

Tags: rasa, nlu

When I am running rasa run actions, it is not showing me the port. I checked with --debug and it is showing the attached message. I don’t know what that means. Can you please help me… When I am running a rasa shell and typing hi, I am getting an error saying that the mentioned message is not present in the domain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's odd. What version of Rasa are you running? Typically you can find the port number preconfigured by checking the `endpoints.yml` file. Could you ensure that the action endpoint is uncommented?

Answer (score 1):

the port number doesn't show in the logs when starting up in recent versions of Rasa Open Source. This has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk/commit/80fe5f82481c703f83a23ec12032303b4a241390) but unfortunately it hasn't been part of an official release yet. We should be releasing one today.

As for your other question, it seems like your NLU model hasn't been trained correctly and is therefore not recognising the intent. Try re-running `rasa train` and check if there are any errors along the way.